# How to access individual views within a scrollView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, viewcontroller

I am pretty new to swift.  I am creating an app that uses a `UIScrollView` to display multiple `UIViews` (like Snapchat). I am trying to implement switches on multiple viewcontrollers contained within the scroll view.

**My goal** is to have all the switches turn off when one switch is turned on, so only one switch can be turned on at a time (so the switches turn off in the other view controllers).

I cannot accomplish this because when you load the scroll view, the sub-views that are contained in it are only loaded once at run time, and when you swipe to the next view/viewcontroller, the viewdidload of the viewcontroller is never called.

Is there a method I can invoke to load or something(or call the other view controller's viewdidLoad) to load the next view controller?

I was not able to find anything on stackoverflow about this. I tried creating a variable of the class and calling a method that had everything that the viewdidload method had of another view, but this did not work. I also tried making a method that had everything that the viewdidload method had a type method, but that did not work either. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `viewDidLoad()` will only get called when the view is loaded.

Alternatively, you can try using multiple `views` placed inside the `scrollView` instead of placing `viewControllers`. If all the views are in the same viewController, then you will be able to add an action to your switches where you can perform the required logic to turn them off.